# Why this copy-initialization (with two implicit conversions) does not work in GCC/Clang?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, copy-initialization

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <string.h>

class cstring {
public:
    cstring(const char* str) : begin_(str), end_(str ? str + strlen(str) : 0)
    {
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return (size_t)(end_ - begin_);
    }

    const char* data() const
    {
        return begin_;
    }

private:
    const char* begin_;
    const char* end_;
};

class Name {
public:
    Name(cstring str)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    cstring str = "Hello World"; // OK

    Name name = str; // OK

    Name name2 = "James"; // error
}
```

Clang will output an error(GCC has similar output):

```
Source.cpp:37:10: error: no viable conversion from 'const char [6]' to 'Name'
    Name name2 = "James"; // error
         ^       ~~~~~~~
Source.cpp:24:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'const char [6]' to 'const Name &' for 1st argument
class Name {
      ^
Source.cpp:26:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [6]' to 'cstring' for 1st
      argument
    Name(cstring str)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

In the above code, due to the non-explicit constructors, `const char*` can be implicitly converted to `cstring`, and `cstring` can be implicitly converted to `Name` as well; hence the conversion sequence from `const char*` to `Name` exists. Then why Clang/GCC disallow such a copy-initialization (msvc allows this case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gcc and clang are correct, only one user-defined conversion is allowed in [implicit conversion sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1. zero or one standard conversion sequence;
> 2. zero or one user-defined conversion;
> 3. zero or one standard conversion sequence.

You could change [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) to [direct-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) as `Name name2 ("James");`, in which only one user-defined conversion (from `const char*` to `cstring`) is required, and the converted `cstring` is passed as the argument to the constructor of `Name` to construct `name2`.

> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce T directly from the initializer, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.